# Which is better to use? Using To.Lower().EndsWith(value) or To.EndsWith(value,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)

Tags: c#

If we have two codes

1. `url.ToLower().EndsWith("_vti_bin/sanjay.aspx")`
2. `url.EndsWith("_vti_bin/sanjay.aspx", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`

Which one is efficient to use and why?

Comment: Who knows... Why don't you profile it and let us know?

Comment: more suited for programmers.stackexchange

Comment: Since neither is *correct*, which is *more efficient* is hardly the question you should be asking. What if your url is `http://example.com/_hello_vti_bin/sanjay.aspx` -- do you want to match that?

Comment: The answer to "which of these things is better?" is always the same. You've written the code both ways. Now **run it both ways**, and then you'll know which one is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second one is more efficient because

1. `ToLower()` is extra function call as compare to 2nd option.
2. `EndsWith(someString)` will call `EndsWith(someString, StringComparison)`

If you de-compile `System.string` (I used ILSpy) you will find this

1. for `EndsWith(str)`

   ```
   [__DynamicallyInvokable]
   public bool EndsWith(string value)
   {
     return this.EndsWith(value, string.LegacyMode ? StringComparison.Ordinal : StringComparison.CurrentCulture);
   }
   ```
2. for `EndsWith(str, StringComparision)`

   ```
   [__DynamicallyInvokable, ComVisible(false), SecuritySafeCritical]
   public bool EndsWith(string value, StringComparison comparisonType)
   {
     .. actual implementation
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

When you absolutely need culturally based linguistic comparisons you should not prefer  `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`, in that case , `ToLower()` is ok ,

otherwise you can use `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` when you want to compare language strings in different cultures.

Answer (score -1):

Second one, in first you are calling two functions.

Comment: This, also depending on the length of the string, the call to `ToLower` may be relatively expensive when all you want to compare is the last ~20 characters.

Comment: @Matthew Yes function keep on making all chars to lower.